# 'Actions for url' missing in Intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Usually, IntelliJ displays a special globe icon with actions for URL when a request handling method is declared, as shown in this pic. [image]

But below my intellij doesn't show the 'Actions for URL' toolbox for some reason, and I don't see any special icon either. Does anyone know why? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Yes, its a missing feature in the Community Edition. I found a work around using Postman. There may be other API tools but I found it easy using Postman. I think you can even use cURL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also following the same tutorial and researched about it. It seems like that you are also using Community Edition. That feature only exists in the Ultimate edition of IntelliJ.

[Integrated developer tools comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TgCn.png)

Source:
https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you're using the Ultimate version and you don't have a globe icon. In that case, You can disable the icon under *Settings/Preferences* -> Editor -> -> Inlay Hints -> Java: check the 'Show hints' box for the 'URL path inlay' option.

[image]

Also note that the globe icons is now different from the IntelliJ IDEA image you shared. See screen shot below:

[image]

The icon is now on the left, next to the line number of the method header.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You can refer to this guide on IntelliJ IDEA community webpage: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010311120-Hide-the-Show-Available-Actions-for-URL-web-icon